# Former Storage Spaces hard drive not showing up in Windows on any PC

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

When HDD is properly retired/removed from Storage Spaces on Windows 10 and then connected to entirely different Windows 10 PC, it doesn't show up in Disk Management console, it isn't automatically mounted, Windows does not prompt the user to format the drive and Storage Spaces UI doesn't show any indication that the HDD is taken by Storage Spaces and hence is invisible to the rest of the PC until Storage Spaces does something with it. You can see the following in Device Manager window (notice the HITACHI drive visible):

[image: Device Manager clearly seeing the HDD being plugged in and connected to the PC.]

When you open Disk Management console, however, the drive isn't visible:

[image: Disk Management clearly not showing the same HDD as available.]

If you try to guess and look into Storage Spaces UI, the HDD isn't listed in there either:

[image: Blank Storage Spaces UI window, not indicating that the HDD is being used by Storage Spaces.]

We can prove, that Storage Spaces is currently grabbing the HDD and preventing rest of the system to see it by running the following Storage Spaces cmdlet in PowerShell: `Get-PhysicalDisk`, which yields the following output:

[image: PowerShell showing that Storage Spaces are occupying the HDD.]

I can see the HDD status as **OK, Starting**. This status never changes, it is forever stuck at this state. How can I make this HDD work in Windows 10 and get rid of Storage Spaces hooking up to it, preventing access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error behavior is still present in Windows 10 as of *build 1909*. The Storage Spaces UI should usually display an option offering to *Reset* the disk (which releases it from Storage Spaces completely), but it isn't doing that sometimes.

The way to resolve this is to run the following sequence of PowerShell commands:

1. Open PowerShell with Administrator privileges (Administrator is required to run this command).
2. Execute cmdlet `Get-PhysicalDisk | select FriendlyName, SerialNumber, UniqueId` This yields following output:

[image: Output of PowerShell cmdlet.]

3. Copy the UniqueId of the HDD in question. In example shown above that is `5000CC2A24E320F6`
4. Execute cmdlet `Reset-PhysicalDisk -UniqueId "5000CC2A24E320F6"`, be sure to replace the `UniqueId` value with your own.

Now the disk is reset and you can see it in Disk Management console:

[image: Disk Management console showing the previously hidden HDD.]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this the exact same issue but I've recently had a real major issue with Storage Spaces in Windows 11 Pro and only managed to recover a near killed drive using Seagates SeaTools and then once finally managing to access the drive I did a zero, ones wipe and the drive is back to being fully operational, however data recovery was impossible.

I've updated the situation on a forum that hasn't banned me from highlighting the truth here...

https://www.windows11forums.com/threads/windows-storage-pool-killed-my-hdd.1570/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think that is basically doing the same thing as described in my approved answer - there seems to be something written to the disk that makes it invisible to regular Disk tools in Windows, because it's considered to be Storage Spaces territory. But because it's also marked as retired by SS, it's ignored there also. Your wipe removed the data causing this, so we both arrived at the same result.

Comment: The unusual part, is why does Windows not provide a way of recovering the drives which it's Pool spaces destroy - for me it's simply not worth the risk or user friendly enough. 

For the average user it's diabolical and they're likely to early end up in a situation of lost data and perfectly serviceable drives which are inaccessible which is another good reason to have this post so people can learn to avoid Windows Pool Storage.